# JSON jdt Replace transformation not working

Tags: json, transformation, devops

I'm trying to transform

```
 { "outputs": [
{ "type": "Sample" },
{
  "type": "Sample1",
  "indexNamePrefix": "Sample2",
  "serviceUri": "Sample3",
  "eventDocumentTypeName": "Sample4"
}
]
}
```

into something like this

```
{ "outputs": [
{ "type": "Sample" },
{
 "type": "Sample1",
 "indexNamePrefix": "Sample2",
 "serviceUri": "NewValue",
 "eventDocumentTypeName": "Sample4"
}
]
}
```

I have tried the couple of transforms based on your examples
 Try 1:
 I just tried to replace the serviceUri which was the only change, following is the transform

```
  {
     "outputs": {
     "@jdt.replace": {
      "@jdt.path": "@[?(@.serviceUri == Sample3)]",
      "@jdt.value": {
        "serviceUri": "NewValue"
      }
    }
    }
    }
```

Result was something like below , which is similar to the transform and doesn't seem like transformation happened

```
{
 "outputs": {
    "@jdt.replace": {
      "@jdt.path": "@[?(@.serviceUri == Sample3)]",
      "@jdt.value": {
        "serviceUri": "NewValue"
      }
    }
}
```

Try 2:
 I tried to replace the entire outputs node

```
{
  "outputs": {
    // Double brackets are needed to specify
    // the array as the transformation value
    "@jdt.replace": [
      [
        {
          "type": "Sample"
        },
        {
          "type": "Sample1",
          "indexNamePrefix": "Sample2",
          "serviceUri": "NewValue",
          "eventDocumentTypeName": "Sample4"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Result was the same as the transform here too , am I missing something ? because the basic remove and rename transforms are working fine.

here is the link I followed https://github.com/Microsoft/json-document-transforms

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have encountered with this issue too. Did you resolved that?